# How to edit c-support (c.vim) snippets

Tags: c++, c, vim

I really dislike the default indentation used on return type of functions, e.g. 
\im (for main function has the return type indented). I would like return type not indented.

Documentation says -- I should rename the snippet $HOME\vimfiles\c-support\codesnippets\main.c to main.c.ni (or main.c.nonindent). But that did not fix the problem.

Any other ideas ?

gvim with c-support by default adds this

```
     int
 main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }              /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

instead, I would like this

```
 int
 main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: Can you give us examples of what VIM does and what you'd like it to do?

Comment: @DeepYellow - I've added what gvim does and what I'd like it to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please, have a look at `:help cinoptions` and `:help cinoptions-values`.

What you want is probably `:set cinoptions=t0` or `:set cinoptions+=t0`.